# How to remove intersections parts of mesh?

Tags: remesh

Hello Blender community ! Blender newbie here...

TL;DR :
I have meshes with intersecting sections, I'd like to be able to slice the intersecting faces to be able to get only the outer shell. Is it possible ? How ?

Long version :
I'm trying to create papercrafts from 3D models coming from many games 3D models, and I have very often problems with parts of meshes getting inside others. I'd like to retrieve only the outer shell from these models, but I still haven't found how I could hollow it.

I've tried separating the original 3D model in many meshes and apply a boolean modifier (in Difference and Union modes) on it, but only one of the 2 parts I want to hollow is actually modified. I'd like both to be removed from the inner part of the model.

I've also tried to use the knife modifier, but once again, I can only cut one face, and after that, the other won't cut, as the 1st one is not intersecting anymore... (And it does not even work every time, as far as I've been able to see)

Does anyone may have a solution to this problem ?

Thanks guys (and girls, I'm sure there are some here too)!

Here are also a few pictures of my actual progress
[image: Solid view of the mesh]
[image: Wired view of the mesh, no boolean applied]
[image: Wired view of the mesh, boolean applied]

Comment: Kindly attach your .blend file here: https://blendexchange.com

Comment: I would recommend that you separate your mesh into only two objects,  one the straight shape and one the two horn-shaped meshes. Then if you use a boolean union modifier, it will be as you want it to be. If you want to delete the intersecting mesh permanently apply the boolean modifier, go into edit mode, and delete the selected mesh. Again, I would ask you to attach your .blend file.

Comment: @YousufChaudhry Thanks for your reply !
I tried to load the blendexchange page, but it does not load at all. You can retrieve the blend file from my own website : http://benoit.tachet.org/AxelChakram.blend

There is actually 8 spikes, 4 small rings, one bigger ring and the 6 parts for the handle, that's why there is that much meshes.

I maybe found a solution by duplicating all the meshes, and using the double ones to create the inner empty part before disabling them and export only the main modified ones. It's an ugly way to do, but it seems to work...

Comment: I'd be glad to try some other ways to solve this problem, I'm pretty sure there is a better solution.

Comment: Would you attach your file to something like WeTransfer or Dropbox? Since your website's not loading at all. (The tab closes in a second after I open it, and no file is downloaded)

Comment: Tab closing is normal, that's a direct link download. Not seeing it in your download manager is kinda weird, though... My website is in HTTP, and not in HTTPS, so that's maybe a security issue.
You can download the file there, it's a 1-week available link : https://wetransfer.com/downloads/2983b9019e48955df43bdbcc9daf7bc220220625200707/898b9da2ef9c4a847b9008ced434619320220625200707/273eda

Comment: Forgot to say : It's an a-bit-more advanced version than the first one. If you want the original version I shared screenshots from, you just have to remove all booleans and *.001 meshes.

Comment: No problem, I'll experiment and see if I can find out something useful ;)

Comment: I tried again with unions instead of differences, it seems to work, but I have to place booleans on many objects, it looks like there is a limit to the number of booleans a single mesh can have.

Comment: I took a shot at it, check my answer :)

Comment: And yes, by the way, your object is purely humongous. Forgot to mention in my answer, but make sure to scale it down a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have **2** solutions to this:

## The Boolean Union

To do this, you have to join each of the replicated objects together. For example, you have 8 spikes. Join the spikes together by selecting them and pressing `Ctrl` + `J`. Now, Then apply the boolean modifier to each of the intersecting objects, for example, add a boolean union on the spike joined object to have a union with the ring joined object. Download the .blend file to see if you didn't get it:

[image]

## The Remesh

Select all your objects and press `Ctrl` + `J` to join. Now, go into edit mode, press `A` to select all, and press `M` > `Merge By Distance`. Now go into sculpt mode, and on the top bar, you will see a `Remesh` tab. Open that tab, set the voxel amount to something between 0.1 to 0.5, and remesh. Remember to enable `Fix Poles` before the remesh on the remesh tab. Add a decimate modifier on top if you want.

Comment: Hi !
Thanks for the try, but I have problems with both solutions :
- Remesh : The shape is correct, but the while item is divided in a lot of small squares, that takes an eternity to calculate...
- Boolean Union : When I try to do it myself, some parts of the mesh just vanish. However, on your version, the parts that are linked seems fine...

Comment: @BenoitTachet After remeshing, you can select all by pressing `A` , and then press `X` > `Limited Dissolve`, or instead of that, you could use the decimate modifier. As for boolean union, the problem at your end must be that you have set some booleans to difference, otherwise you could always copy paste the objects/mesh from my file ;)

Comment: Well, I just tried with another computer, everything seems to work well with boolean union, but I have just a small problem with the "inner Handle" parts that do not union correctly : One of them seems to keep its faces inside of the mesh, but the other not.

Comment: Hold it ! I found why it didn't work ! (Because some parts of the handle were still in the "Axel Chakram" part, and thus, the inner faces were kept. By linking these faces to their corresponding part, it seems to be good.

Comment: @BenoitTachet Well, if it solved your problem, consider accepting the answer by clicking the checkbox on the left ;)

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to check if this was really the solution, but after check, it seems to be correct for good. Thank you for your help !

Comment: @BenoitTachet No problem, have fun !)

Comment: Small update to the answer : I recently discovered the face->intersect(knife) tool that is quite useful to split faces (I tried the hand knife that was hard to use for this, but this one works really fine).

Comment: @BenoitTachet You could answer your own question yourself ;)