# Split faces of a mesh in two

Tags: modeling, mesh, faces

Question following my previous one ([here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/267495/how-to-remove-intersections-parts-of-mesh/267592?noredirect=1#comment458084_267592))
I have a model that I retrieved from a game (Kingdom Hearts 2, if you want to know everything), that I'd like to create as a papercraft model. However, in order to do that, I need a clean 3D model, with no overlapping faces, and this one was clearly not fitting the case.
I removed most of the overlapping mesh parts by separating the main sections and using union modifiers, but some parts still do not fit.

Here is a view of the whole mesh, without texture.

[image]

A view of a half of the handle

[image]

And here is a view of one of the faces from the center handle, which is not separated correctly. There is just one face, but it's more 2 pieces than one (the striped part should not be here...)

[image]

A clean version from another face (but the 2 parts are still linked in blender)

[image]

Finally, here is a view of the software I use to unfold the 3D model. That's the sections of the handle, that really do not fit correctly. I don't know why, but it looks like it adds some materials to the mesh to be able to do its job...

[image]

Is there a way to fix these faces so they can fit correctly ? (maybe by splitting them in half in the X and the Y axis, for each half ? I've tried to do this, but with no success)

The current blend file :
[image]

Comment: I might model the whole thing from scratch at this point. It doesn’t look very tricky.

Comment: If you want to split faces of a mesh in two, I would suggest subdivide ( select the faces, click on edge, then subdivide in editmode) or loopcut tool, but that doesn't really seem to be your question anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no experience in model creation, that's why I'm trying to start from an existing model. There are other models from these games I'd like to create, that have similar problems, and much harder to recreate,...

Comment: @BentleyCarpenter Yeah, I tried subdividing, but here, Blender considers there is only one triangle in each case of the pictures I shared. I don't even understand why on the first one, there is this "ghost" section...

Comment: @BentleyCarpenter the .blend file is already linked in my answer in the question he linked... So you could download it from there.

Comment: @BenoitTachet Maybe apply the boolean modifier and clean up the model? Or select all and go to faces > Tris to Quads?

Comment: Uploaded the .blend file again, it's easier from having to seek it from somewhere else.

Comment: @YousufChaudhry there is only one face, so I don't think a boolean modifuer will change anything (unless I haven't understood how it does work...)

Comment: I just fixed the problem on my computer by removing boolean modifier from every object. Now there are no overlapping faces at all.

Comment: @BentleyCarpenter you should read the previous question then..... ;)

Comment: @BenoitTachet Apply the boolean modifier (I do not mean add the boolean modifier, but apply the already added boolean) through the dropdown on the modifier tab and then manually clean up the mesh, that might work.

Comment: @BenoitTachet Or (I am going back to the previous question) you could use the remesh method and use a decimate modifier to reduce the poly count.

Comment: @YousufChaudhry Oops :|  I clearly didn't get enough coffee this morning...

Comment: @BentleyCarpenter No problem, it happens to everyone ^^

Comment: @YousufChaudhry remodeling makes an even worse mess in my unfolding software, even with a large scale (tried with 0.1m and 0.5m, I have a very similar result).

Comment: Hello again guys,
I finally started again from scratch, by reusing all the informations I have on the vertices positions from the original model. However, that won't be a solution for more complex models...